# Can hive tables that contain DATE type columns be queried using impala?

Tags: hive, impala

Everytime I am trying to select in IMPALA a DATE type field from a table created in HIVE I get the AnalysisException: Unsupported type 'DATE'.

Are there any workarounds?

**UPDATE** this is an example of a create table schema from hive and an impala query

**Schema:**

CREATE TABLE `myschema.mytable`(`day_dt` date,
`event` string)

PARTITIONED BY (`day_id` int)

STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'

OUTPUTFORMAT 
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'

**Impala query**
select b.day_dt
from myschema.mytable b;

Comment: Consider using `TIMESTAMP` data type for better interoperability

Comment: The hive table I am trying to query is already created and cannot be altered. Any solution for working with the current schema in impala?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Impala doesn't have a `DATE` datatype, whereas Hive has. You will get `AnalysisException: Unsupported type 'DATE'` when you access it from Impala.  A quick fix would be to create a `string` column of that `date` value in Hive and access it in whichever way you want from Impala.

Comment: It saved my day. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

If you're storing as strings, it may work to create a new external hive table that points to the same HDFS location as the existing table, but with the schema having day_dt with datatype STRING instead of DATE.

This is a true workaround, it may only suit some use cases, and you'd at least need to do "MSCK REPAIR" on the external hive table whenever a new partition is added.